# Is it possible to type equations as text in Mathematica?

Tags: text

I was wondering if I could write an equation, symbolically, but only as part of a text in Mathematica. So I don't want Mathematica to consider anything inside that equation as a variable, nor equate or perform any mathematics on it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can open a text cell using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>, and type some text.  When you need math, open a subcell using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>.  Single letter variables will be formatted in italics in the subcell, as is usual. Use the [usual shortcuts](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html) (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> for superscript) to enter math. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to get out of the subcell (or the arrow keys).

On a Mac, use <kbd>⌘</kbd> in place of <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: If your using a Mac, substitute Command (open Apple) for Alt.

Comment: Somehow it seems more natural to me to think of the delimiters for inline (math) mode as Ctrl ( and Ctrl ). Especially with their suggestion of open - close.

Comment: In Mathematica 11.3 on OSX it's ^9 to start an inline cell and ^0 to end it. ⌘7 still seems to open a text cell.